# Improve Linux kernel compile time by disabling specific modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have to compile the Linux kernel quite frequently for a device with a limited use-case. Naturally, I don't need most of the modules of the Linux kernel. Is there a good way to determine which modules I can disable to improve the compile speed as much as possible.
I've already disabled a bunch of modules which I know I don't need. But I'd like to know which specific modules would give me the most gain in compilation speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `.config` appropriate for your system (more precisely, enabling only modules which are currently loaded) by running

```
make localmodconfig
```

if you want modules or

```
make localyesconfig
```

if you want a static build.

This will avoid building any modules which your system doesn’t need, thus achieving your goal: “to improve the compile speed as much as possible”.

Comment: I already have a custom config. This question is more about how to figure out which modules would help me most by disabling them. Sorry if that wasn't clear from the original question.

Comment: That’s what I’d gathered from your question; the purpose of my answer was to explain how to get a configuration specific to your question, thus eliminating as many modules as possible, “to improve the compile speed as much as possible” as specified in your question.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I misunderstood. I didn't know that was a possibility. Thank you

Comment: Apologies, that should be “specific to your system”, not “specific to your question”.

Comment: What if I don't have a preference regarding mod/static and I just want what is recommended?

Comment: The machine in question doesn't have make, gcc, etc. installed. Can I do it on another machine instead, by using the lsmod output or something similar? The other machine has a different architecture and kernel version

Comment: @Philippe Regarding modules versus static, if you have no preference, you almost certainly want modules and not static. There are significant benefits to using modules for drivers that are not essential for the system to boot over having them all linked in, and some drivers actually _require_ this usage if you don’t want to jump through hoops to bake their associated firmware into the kernel image (which you should almost never do).